# How to rebase other references to PlanningEntity in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I'm using multithreaded solving. I have a PlanningEntity that indirectly has references to other objects of the same class:

```
@PlanningEntity
class A {
  @PlanningId
  public int id;

  public List<B> bList;

  @InverseRelationShadowVariable
  public List<C> shadowVariable;
}

class B {
  public A a;
}
```

As you can see, class A contains a shadow variable that needs to remain updated. This works fine when directly referencing an object of A. However, when I do `a.bList.get(0).a`, this refers to another instance of a, the original one which has not been rebased to the current solver thread (and as such, the shadow variable is not updated).

Is there a way to tell OptaPlanner that these references exist and that they should be updated when rebasing the problem to another thread?

(I think PlanningVariableReference looks like it might be related to my problem but the documentation isn't very clear.)